# Raspberry pi zero and Mini thermal printer issue

Tags: raspberry-pi, thermal-printer, adafruit

I'm using the Adafruit Mini thermal printer and Raspberry Pi Zero W with Raspian Jessie.
I'm following this tutorial [Raspberry Thermal Network Printer](https://learn.adafruit.com/networked-thermal-printer-using-cups-and-raspberry-pi?view=all), i connected everything via TTL.

I tried 
`stty -F /dev/serial0 19200`but the port serial0 doesn't exist for me, so i tried printing down the port list with `ls /dev/tty*`but it seems that the raspberry doesn't recognize the printer because when i print it with the thermal printer connected or disconnected is exactly the same.

I also tried with the ports "ttyAMA0" and "serial1" that exist in my /dev directory but when i run `echo -e "This is a test.\\n\\n\\n" > /dev/serial1`, it stuck.

My printer prints correctly the test page when i hold down the button while powering up, i also tried changing Raspberry Zero (with Stretch installed) and changing the power of the Raspberry and of the printer.

Do you have any idea of what could be the problem?

Thank you

Matteo

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `sudo raspi-config` and enabling the serial ports?